# Can I use different argument separators for macros than comma?

Tags: c++, macros

Is there a way to write a C++ macro with arguments which are not separated by a comma but any other character or even a space?

**Example**: I was just thinking about a lightweight way to have typed and named parameter to replace a call like this:

```
foo("value", (int)0);
```

with something like

```
foo(ARG(string key = "some_key"), 
    ARG(int value = 0));
```

which could be pre-processed to

```
foo(static_cast<string>("some_key"), static_cast<int>(0));
```

Of course this would be possible with using commas but I'm just curious..

Comment: No it is not possible.   The C++ preprocessor is not a general-purpose compiler.  It does a particular range of operations on source code involving text substitution.   Transformations like you describe are not within the range of possibilities.

Comment: Could you explain why that would be an improvement?

Comment: Why what would what be an improvement? Different separators or the alternative way to write `foo("value", (int)0);`?

Comment: If you are looking for creative ways to shoot yourself in the foot, C++ has much to offer beyond macros.

Comment: Since `key` and `value` vanish from the desired preprocessed output, why not use comments? `foo(string/*key*/{"some_key"}, int/*value*/{0})`

Comment: Well, you can do it the hard way: write a script using any language you like that does this, then run it before each build by adding a pre-build event in whichever build system you are using.

Comment: You can write template wrapper for function calls wich will cast all input args into their expected types, but compiller already does it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to write a C++ macro with arguments which are not separated by a comma but any other character or even a space?

No, the preprocessor specification does not provide any way of changing the separator character.

---

> I was just thinking about a lightweight way to have typed and named parameter to replace a call like this:
>
> ```
> foo(ARG(string key = "some_key"), 
>     ARG(int value = 0));
> ```

That can be implemented with templates overloading `operator=`. Louis Dionne showed a possible example implementation at this year's Meeting C++ keynote: [you can find it here](http://ldionne.com/meetingcpp-2016/#/21).

The final syntax looks like:

```
int main() {
  create_window("x"_arg = 20, "y"_arg = 50,
                "width"_arg = 100, "height"_arg = 5);
}
```

Other implementations with different syntax are possible - the point is that you do not need the preprocessor for this.

A production-ready example is the [Boost Parameter Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the C / C++ preprocessor for that.

But you could generate your C++ code with another preprocessor, such as [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html) or [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp).

And you can also write your own, ad-hoc, C++ code emitter.